# Counting elements of an array in a new column of a data frame row by row

Tags: arrays, pandas, dataframe, count

I didn't find a solution in the forum that helped me.
I have a very big data frame of transportation data. One of my 33 columns of my data frame is an array which includes the allowed labels of the solution (of this row).

So the column is:

```
usedLabels

[db_fv, blablacar, flixbus]

[db_fv, blablacar, flixbus]

[db_fv, blablacar, flixbus, airplane]

[db_fv, blablacar]
```

and I want to add a column that counts the entry of each array per row:

```
usedLabelsCount

3

3

4

2
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
size = 1
for dim in df['usedLabels']: size *= dim
    
df['usedLabelsCount'] = df.set_index(['usedLabels']).count(level="usedLabels")
df['usedLabelsCount'] = len(df['usedLabels'])

df['usedLabelsCount'] = df['usedLabels'].count
```

my results with `.count` is:

```
<bound method Series.count of 0 [db_fv...>
```

and with `len` I get the count of all rows (and not for each row). So each row of usedLabelsCount would contain 903829 (which is the overall count and not per row)

Thank you!

Edit:
The suggested solution (see below) didn't quite work:

```
df['UsedLabelsCount']=[len(i) for i in df['usedLabels']]
```

I tried it, but now it counts 27. Which is the overall unique value of the labels (and not per row). I don't know why.. I tried this too:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows(): a = (len(i) for i in df['usedLabels']) df['usedLabelsCount']= a
```

but this prints that error into the data frame (the codes runs): `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f9566666c80>`
any ideas?

Edit 2:
so this is some sample data:

> https://github.com/Hektor1997/sample-data.git

Comment: Could you provide some sample data for the frame such that your issue can be reproduced?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
df['UsedLabelsCount']=[len(i) for i in df['usedLabels']]
```

Comment: thanks! I tried it, but now it counts 27. Which is the overall unique value of the labels. I don't know why.. 

I tried this too: 
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    a = (len(i) for i in df['usedLabels'])
df['usedLabelsCount']= a

but this prints that error into the data frame (the codes runs):
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f9566666c80>

any ideas?

Comment: @magicunicorncoding are you sure that the series contains lists?

Comment: I am not sure - I assume that some columns in my data frame contain arrays. But I am not sure how to verify. dtype is just object. @suhas-mucherla